# Migrating from Magento 1 to 2

Tags: magento-1, migration

Our site still uses Magento 1.6.  If someone knows a reliable professional who can help us migrate to the latest Magento 2, please recommend. Thank you.

Comment: https://www.upwork.com/o/companies/~0169580536a5e9eda5/

Comment: Contact with them, they are very professionals